# Failed to decode the downloaded font glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 - Rails, Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-face

Im using the bootstrap3-wysihtml5 and some of the icons are using glyphicons font.

Im having problems using the glyphicons-halflings-regular font in my rails application when its running in production. My chrome browser console is showing

```
Failed to decode the downloaded font
```

and the font-icons are not showing. I see a square around where the icons should show. The fonts seems to be working locally even if precompile locally and run as production locally. Im running assets precompile in production.

My fonts were originally located in the vendor directory under plugins and appended the path the config.assets.paths.

I've ensured the paths are correct in the CSS file because i can successfully access the file via browser url. And the fact that the console warning shows "Failed to decode downloaded font" means it has access to it. Just cant understand the file.

I've also tried registering the Mimetypes in the rails mimetype config:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/x-font-woff', :woff 
Mime::Type.register 'application/font-woff2', :woff2 
Mime::Type.register 'application/x-font-ttf', :ttf 
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject', :eot
```

I've also tried moving the fonts out of the asset pipeline by placing them in the public folder and referencing accordingly but I get the same issue.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can resolve this?

Using: 
Rails 4.1.6
Ruby 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I met this experience before. It was solved by downloading the latest version of the bootstrap 3 fonts and replace them.